# Obter o item selecionado na TreeView do iView

Tags: vue.js, treeview, vue.js-2

Preciso obter a referência do item selecionado na `TreeView` do `iView`, já tentei com `getSelectedNodes()` mas parece que o método não está sendo usado corretamente, e a documentação não ajuda muito...

```js
    var Main = {
        data () {
            return {
                data1: [
                    {
                        title: 'parent 1',
                        expand: false,
                        children: [
                            {
                                title: 'parent 1-1',
                                expand: false,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        title: 'leaf 1-1-1'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'leaf 1-1-2'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'parent 1-2',
                                expand: false,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        title: 'leaf 1-2-1'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'leaf 1-2-1'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods : {
          getSelectedNodes (el) {
            console.log(el);
          }
        }
    }

var Component = Vue.extend(Main)
new Component().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/iview/dist/styles/iview.css");
#app{padding: 32px;}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <tree :data="data1"></tree>
</div>
```

Se possível, gostaria de saber também, como posso instanciar um evento de `click` para cada item.

Comment: À parte: comenta aqui ou lá que parte da documentação achas insuficiente para podermos melhorar.

Comment: @Sergio, parabéns pelo projeto, em relação a documentação, achei meio vago na sessão da `TreeView` e posso estar enganado mas aonde está o método `on-select-change` o titulo está como 'Tree events' e `getCheckedNodes` com o titulo 'Tree methods' ou seja, `getCheckedNodes` eu estava colocando em `methods`, e `on-select-change` imaginava como uma diretiva...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nota à parte: eu sou [membro ativo](https://github.com/iview/iview/graphs/contributors) do iView. E tenho gosto em ajudar perguntas relacionadas mas nem sempre as vejo a tempo.

Podes usar o `@on-select-change` para saber quais os elementos selecionados quando um deles é selecionado/de-selecionado, e podes também usar o `getSelectedNodes` mas nesse caso precisas de uma referência ao componente:

```
const tree = this.$refs.tree;
const allSelected = tree.getSelectedNodes();
```

Exemplo:

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      data1: [{
        title: 'parent 1',
        expand: true,
        children: [{
            title: 'parent 1-1',
            expand: true,
            children: [{
                title: 'leaf 1-1-1'
              },
              {
                title: 'leaf 1-1-2'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            title: 'parent 1-2',
            expand: false,
            children: [{
                title: 'leaf 1-2-1'
              },
              {
                title: 'leaf 1-2-1'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSelectChange(selected) {
      console.log('onSelectChange', selected);
    },
    onCheckSelected() {
      const tree = this.$refs.tree;
      const allSelected = tree.getSelectedNodes();
      console.log('allSelected:', allSelected);
    }
  }
}

var Component = Vue.extend(Main)
new Component().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/iview/dist/styles/iview.css");
#app {
  padding: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tree :data="data1" multiple @on-select-change="onSelectChange" ref="tree"></tree>
  <i-button @click="onCheckSelected">Saber todos os selecionados</i-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui mas não tenho certeza se é a melhor forma para fazer...

```js
    var Main = {
        data () {
            return {
              estiloFilhosTree : {
                  color: 'white',
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  background: '#424242',
                  padding: '1px 4px',
                  letterSpacing: '1px',
                  fontSize : '11px'
                },
                data1: [
                    {
                        title: 'MARGIN',
                        expand: false,
                        render : (h, {root, node, data}) => {
                         return h('span', {
                            style : this.estiloFilhosTree,
                             on: {
                              click: () => { console.log(data.title) }
                             }
                            }, data.title) 
                        },
                        children: [
                            {
                                title: 'MARGIN-TOP',
                                expand: false,
                                render : (h, {root, node, data}) => {
                                  return h('span', {
                                    style : this.estiloFilhosTree,
                                     on: {
                                      click: () => { console.log(data.title) }
                                     }
                                    }, data.title) 
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'MARGIN-BUTTON',
                                expand: false,
                                render : (h, {root, node, data}) => {
                                  return h('span', {
                                    style : this.estiloFilhosTree,
                                     on: {
                                      click: () => { console.log(data.title) }
                                     }
                                    }, data.title) 
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'PADDING',
                        expand: false,
                        render : (h, {root, node, data}) => {
                         return h('span', {
                            style : this.estiloFilhosTree,
                             on: {
                              click: () => { console.log(data.title) }
                             }
                            }, data.title) 
                        },
                        children: [
                            {
                                title: 'PADDING-TOP',
                                expand: false,
                                render : (h, {root, node, data}) => {
                                  return h('span', {
                                    style : this.estiloFilhosTree,
                                     on: {
                                      click: () => { console.log(data.title) }
                                     }
                                    }, data.title) 
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'PADDING-BUTTON',
                                expand: false,
                                disabled : true,
                                render : (h, {root, node, data}) => {
                                  return h('span', {
                                    style : this.estiloFilhosTree,
                                     on: {
                                      click: () => { console.log(data) }
                                     }
                                    }, data.title) 
                                },
                            children: [{
                                 title: 'oi'
                               }]
                             }   
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }

var Component = Vue.extend(Main)
new Component().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/iview/dist/styles/iview.css");
#app{padding: 32px;}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <tree :data="data1"></tree>
</div>
```

Para cada item, instanciei um render que retorna `root`, `node` e `data`, sendo `data` a referência do item.